# Possible to CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION with a different owner?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, event-notification

We are in the process of removing a previous dba login and he owns all the endpoints and event notification objects. Endpoints were easy to change; Event notification objects not so much.

I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f68d3832-07e4-48eb-8c28-c668f3acd8a4/unable-to-delete-login-user?forum=sqlsecurity) about changing the owner of an event notification object (you have to drop and recreate). I don't want to go through this process again if I can avoid it. I doubt it's possible, but outside of logging in as another user, can you create an event notification that runs as sa, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` might offer a way to transfer ownership, but no, [according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Ownership of the following entities **cannot be transferred**: <many things> and **event notifications**.

So, script them, drop them, and re-create them under a more generic account that is not tied to an employee.  As an aside, [you can use PSExec to log in under a service account, like NT Authority\System](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/), and use that account to create the notification.

This is similar to things like the `ANSI_NULLS` setting for tables (which I dealt with recently re: persisted computed columns).

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION` inside `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'sa'; ... REVERT;` allows creation of a server event notification as if you logged in using the `sa` account, even if that account is disabled.

A very minimal example follows.  First we'll check to see if the `[sa]` login is disabled:

```
/* Is the [sa] login disabled? */
SELECT 
      [sp].[name]
    , [sp].[sid]
    , [sp].[is_disabled]
FROM [sys].[server_principals] [sp]
WHERE [sp].[sid] = 0x01;
```

| name | sid | is_disabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sa | 0x01 | 1 |

Create the event notification:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'sa';
CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION [notification_name]
    ON SERVER
    FOR <event list>
    TO SERVICE N'service_name', N'current database';
REVERT;
```

Then check ownership of the server event notification via this query:

```
SELECT 
    [owner] = sp.[name]
    , sen.*
FROM [sys].[server_event_notifications] sen
    INNER JOIN [sys].[server_principals] sp ON sen.[principal_id] = [sp].[principal_id];
```

| owner | name | object_id | parent_class | parent_class_desc | parent_id | create_date | modify_date | service_name | broker_instance | creator_sid | principal_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sa | notification_name | 647673355 | 100 | SERVER | 0 | 2022-12-07 10:58:31.700 | 2022-12-07 10:58:31.700 | service_name | 073682F8-D45B-4C41-9FD9-523C90F662A2 | NULL | 1 |

As you can see in the results above, the owner is now `sa`.